# How to generate and serve favicons with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, favicon

So I have a universal React project set up, and need to serve favicons in an Html.js component which is rendered server-side.

I'm interested in using [this package](https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin), as it seems to automatically bounce 30+ different sizes of favicons automatically.

Here's what I've done so far:

**Html.js**:

```
...
import faviconUrl from 'universal/images/favicon.png'

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='icon' href={faviconUrl} />
  </head>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
...
plugins: [
  new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({logo:'universal/images/favicon.png', inject: true})
]
```

However, when I build and do `npm start`, I get this error:

```
[Error] SyntaxError: /universal/images/favicon.png: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) > 1 | �PNG
```

Obviously, webpack is not expecting that import to be a binary file, but why? Any advice or recommendations on easy ways to get favicons going would be appreciated.

Comment: If you happen to have _HtmlWebpackPlugin_ in your stack, there is a [configuration setting](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin#configuration) for favicons.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) and set it up in `loaders` section like:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
    loader: 'url',
    query: {
        name: '[path][name].[ext]'
    }
},
```